# jQuery Chaining animation one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am using the following functions to grow the text box and display the submit button on focus and shrink and hide the button on blur.

But the button shows and hides before the animation is complete.

I am looking to create a neat slide down and slide up animation.

```
$('#venue-write-review').focus(function() {
    $(this).animate({ height: '96px' }, 500);
    $('#submit-review').show();
});
$('#venue-write-review').blur(function() {
    $(this).animate({ height: '48px' }, 500);
    $('#submit-review').hide();
});
```

Comment: animate accepts a complete callback, check DOC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need <sub>And don't forget to use `.stop()`!</sub>

```
$('#venue-write-review').on('focus blur',function(e){
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: e.type[0]=="f"?96:48 }, 500, function(){
         $('#submit-review').toggle();
    }); 
});
```

`e.type[0]=="f"` ij just to check in a *Conditional Operator (?:)* if the passed event's first `[0]` character is `f` (*focus*; else logically it's *blur*)

Read the **jQuery** docs about the methods: `.on()`, `.toggle()`, `stop()` `.animate() callback` and on the **MDN** website read about *Conditional operator*

Also in jQuery if you don't need to animate by `%` or some other measure, you don't need to specify `'px'` cause it's default.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a callback to the animate function to be executed once the animation is done.

```
$('#venue-write-review')
    .focus(function() {
        $(this).animate({ height: '96px' }, 500, function () {
            $('#submit-review').show();
        });
    })
    .blur(function() {
        $(this).animate({ height: '48px' }, 500, function () {
            $('#submit-review').hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: cache your `$('#submit-review')` selectors

Answer (score 1):

You can use `complete` callback. Check the [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) (*under options section*):

> A function to call once the animation is complete.

Like this:

```
$('#venue-write-review').focus(function() {
    $(this).animate({
            height: '96px'
        }, 
        {
            duration: 500,
            complete: function() { 
                $('#submit-review').show();
            }
        }
    });
});

$('#venue-write-review').blur(function() {
    $(this).animate({
            height: '48px'
        }, 
        {
            duration: 500,
            complete: function() { 
                $('#submit-review').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```